# Should you highlight an editorial written about your research article in your CV?

Tags: cv

Some journals invite well-known academics to write editorials about the "best" articles featured in that issue. I just had an editorial published alongside a paper I just put out. Should I highlight this somewhere in my CV? I didn't write the editorial and it's not exactly media coverage, but I'm a young academic, so I'll take anything I can get!

Comment: I don't see any reason why you shouldn't. It is a pretty significant distinction for a paper to be covered by an editorial.

Comment: How would you do this? A comment saying "Featured in an editorial in the same issue" after the citation?

Answer (score 3):

You'll likely include a list of publications sorted by publication type (e.g., book, book chapter, edited book, journal article, ...), you can add a list  headed "Media coverage", "Press coverage", or similar.

Answer (score 1):

It's better than media coverage, since it's a published endorsement by a subject-matter expert.  I would say that this falls under the category of a "measure of esteem" and so it is perfectly reasonable to add it to your CV.  If this happened to me, I would certainly feature it!